# What type of normalization happens with sklearn

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, normalize

I have a matrix which I'm trying to normalize by transforming each feature column to zero mean and unit standard deviation.

I have the following code that I'm using, but I want to know if that method actually does what I'm trying to or if it uses a different method.

```
from sklearn import preprocessing

mat_normalized = preprocessing.normalize(mat_from_df)
```

Comment: It is simply vector normalization http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.normalize.html

Comment: Always read the documentation before using anything.

Comment: I see. Is there a scikit learn method that achieves what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Yes.  `preprocessing.scale`

Comment: Thank you! Can you post that as an answer so I can mark it and upvote it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sklearn.preprocessing.normalize` scales each sample vector to unit norm.  (The default axis is 1, not 0.)  Here's proof of that:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize

np.random.seed(444)
data = np.random.normal(loc=5, scale=2, size=(15, 2))
np.linalg.norm(normalize(data), axis=1)
# array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1., ...
```

It sounds like you're looking for `sklearn.preprocessing.scale` to scale each feature vector to ~N(0, 1).

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale

# Are the scaled column-wise means approx. 0.?
np.allclose(scale(data).mean(axis=0), 0.)
# True

# Are the scaled column-wise stdevs. approx. 1.?
np.allclose(scale(data).std(axis=0), 1.)
# True
```

Answer (score 1):

Like [the documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.normalize.html) states:

> ```
> sklearn.preprocessing.normalize(X, norm='l2',
>                                 axis=1, copy=True,
>                                 return_norm=False)
> ```
>
> Scale input vectors individually to unit norm (vector length).

So it takes the norm (by default the L2 norm) and then ensures that the vector is unit.

So if we take as input an *n×m*-matrix, the output is an *n×m*-matrix. Every *m*-vector is normalized. For `norm='l2'` (the default), thus this means that the length is calculated (by the square root of the sum of the square of the components), and every element is divided by that length, such that the result is a vector with length `1`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain it. I know I should read the documentation more, but sometimes I still can't fully understand it.